# How can I print a variable into a JPanel and then use the main method to re-print the variable when it changes?

Tags: java, variables, methods, jpanel, program-entry-point

Here's my code; https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8ef69a391c6c4e37b92

I've tried placing the "label1.setText("Bouncing bouncing ball" + bounceCount);" into the main method, but of course the variable bounceCount is a class variable and cannot be used inside the main method, is there any way around this?

Comment: No links please -- all code should go here with your post. For one there's no need to do this since if your code is too big to post here, then it's too big to ask volunteers to go through. Again, please remember that we're all volunteers, and so you should try to make it as easy as possible for us to help you. So please help us by posting your code here with your question, preferably as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1. Add a 'getter' method in your game class.

```
public int getBounceCount() {
    return bounceCount;
}
```

and then:

```
   while (true) {
        game.moveBall();
        game.checkBounceCount();
        //JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        //label1.setText("Bouncing bouncing ball" + game.getBounceCount());
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
```

2. Your second option (and a much better one), is to have your main game loop within a different thread. You could even implement the 'runnable' interface in your class.

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
  //...
  public void run() {
    //Your game's main animation loop
    while (true) {
       //Do your thing
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the main method:

```
Thread gameLoop = new Thread(game);
gameLoop.start();
```